# A reference for beginners in Fourier series

Tags: reference-request, fourier-series

I am looking for a good reference for beginners to study Fourier series, with some numerical applications, including FFT, and (a lot of ) easy exercices.

Comment: I like this book: https://bookstore.ams.org/stml-63 Might be more theoretical than you prefer but the authors do a good job of making it readable.

Comment: Thank you, seems excellent !